# I am looking for a good resource on ownerdrawn treeviews

Tags: c#, winforms

I am running into problems with drawing my treeview.

design goals:

Level 0 should work just like default with out checkboxes

Level 1 should have check boxes

Level 2 should not have check boxes

I have for the most part been able to create this behaiviour but I am not able to get ome parts to redraw properly:

On level-0 the plusminus is missing and

c#, winforms, .net-2.0

on Level-1 the node lines are missing

on level-2 the node lines are missing

does any one have any experiance with something similar or can point me to an online resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete ownerdraw of TreeView is hard.  It is so hard that Lutz Roeder of Reflector fame didn't implement it fully.  It is so hard that even Microsoft gave up on it.  Consider the Windows 7 style:

[image]

Note the black triangle for an expanded node, the hollow one for a collapsed node.  Esthetically pleasing, very easy to implement yourself and your app will automatically be ready for the Win7 look.  Win win.