# Hiding Checkboxes with a Tri-State TreeView control

Tags: image, c#-4.0, treeview, tri-state-logic

I have a project that I'm working on that has a TreeView Control in it.  For everything underneath Level 1, those nodes are being used as a bookmark function, so we want a Tri-State CheckBox there.  I found a control that I'm using [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6549/Tri-State-TreeView-Control).

However, as the top two levels in the TreeView do not need bookmarking, the customer wants an Image there.  I found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826556/treeview-remove-checkbox-by-some-nodes) who's response gets CheckBoxes to disappear on specific Nodes.  Unfortunately, the API calls clash with the ones used in the above Tri-State TreeView and they both can't work at the same time.

Basically, what I'm looking for is how to get Images in nodes on the top two levels, and Tri-State CheckBoxes on the lower levels.  I'd be more than willing to try another Tri-State CheckBox if necessary.

Also, when the user clicks on the Image in the top two levels, the image shouldn't change.  I found [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/winforms/thread/5F122C49-F83C-4413-B68F-2237F809DCEF) which does keep the image from changing, but removes the PlusMinus, Lines, and RootLines from the control.

Sorry in advance that this is such a ridiculous and specific request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got this figured out.  Using the [Tri-State Treeview Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6549/Tri-State-TreeView-Control), I am able to still have access to the AfterClick event on the Treeview.

I had added a series of Checkbox icons to the ImageList, and after determining which CheckState (of the 3) my underlying object was in.  Then I set the ImageIndex, SelectedImageIndex, and StateImageIndex (probably don't need the last one, but I was being thorough) to the proper index of the ImageList.

I won't post any code for now, but if you are trying to do the same thing, let me know and I'll upload until it becomes clear.