# Changing the backcolor of a childnode in the treeview

Tags: c#, user-interface, treeview, components

As per [TreeView Remove CheckBox by some Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4826556/2470362)

After doing so I have my `tree-view` of `check-box` without `parent node check-box`.
But I am facing a problem, I am not able to change the color of a particular child node.

ie. if i try to change like

```
treeview1.Nodes[0].Nodes[2].BackColor=Color.Gray;
```

is still having the same old color.
Can anyone help me on this. 
Thanks.

Edited

```
private const int TVIF_STATE = 0x8;
    private const int TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK = 0xF000;
    private const int TV_FIRST = 0x1100;
    private const int TVM_SETITEM = TV_FIRST + 63;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private struct TVITEM
    {
        public int mask;
        public IntPtr hItem;
        public int state;
        public int stateMask;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string lpszText;
        public int cchTextMax;
        public int iImage;
        public int iSelectedImage;
        public int cChildren;
        public IntPtr lParam;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam,
                                             ref TVITEM lParam);

    /// <summary> 
    /// Hides the checkbox for the specified node on a TreeView control. 
    /// </summary> 
    private void HideCheckBox(TreeView tvw, TreeNode node)
    {
        TVITEM tvi = new TVITEM();
        tvi.hItem = node.Handle;
        tvi.mask = TVIF_STATE;
        tvi.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
        tvi.state = 0;
        SendMessage(tvw.Handle, TVM_SETITEM, IntPtr.Zero, ref tvi);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the DrawNode event of the treeView1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Forms.DrawTreeNodeEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Level == 0)
            HideCheckBox(e.Node.TreeView, e.Node);
        e.DrawDefault = true;           
    }




    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {          

        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: I tested it and it worked OK for me. Where do you call this `treeview1.Nodes[0].Nodes[2].BackColor=Color.Gray;`?

Comment: i am calling it on treeView1_AfterSelect
King. have ur parent node is of checkbox ?

Comment: Well, tested and it also works. your problem is strange enough.

Comment: King can u plz tell me how u have done?

Comment: I've done exactly what you described. I used the code of `Cody Gray` from the link you posted, hide the checkbox I want, then add the code you posted in a `AfterSelect` event handler, that's all. It works normally.

Comment: BTW, why do you want to change the BackColor of a **fixed node** while I thought you should have changed the BackColor of the **selected node** in the `AfterSelect` event handler.

Comment: Hi King its not about fixed node. i am trying to highlight some node based on some condition. i will edit the above ques and u can c how i have implemented. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried it the way you did (specially the `DrawNode` event handler) and I'm pretty sure that you set `TreeView.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;`. That won't draw the `Background` (just `Text` only) so that's why the `BackColor` is not updated. You have to set it to `TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll` instead:

I would use another approach to `Hide` all the `Child node checkboxes` without using `DrawNode` event handler. I would add code to the `BeforeExpand` like this:

```
 //BeforeExpand event handler for your TreeView
 private void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e){
   foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Nodes) 
       HideCheckBox(e.Node.TreeView, e.Node);
 }
```

You can also loop through all the nodes with `level>0` to hide the checkbox **once**. Then whenever you add more nodes to your `TreeView`, if it's not `level 0 node`, just `HideCheckBox` right after adding it.

**NOTE**: Of course the 2 approaches I mentioned above **don't** require you to set `DrawMode` to anything other than `Normal`.

Comment: Thanks King
this was the problem... 

i was using OwnerDrawText instead of OwnerDrawAll

Comment: @Abin yes, that's what I mentioned in my answer. However I recommend you to use the 2 approaches I posted in my answer. Using `BeforeExpand` is the cleanest way.